# How do you implement totals from usage output generated by a program in a script so that they carry on sanely through repeated execution?

Tags: shell, columns, statistics

I have a script with a pipeline where the data is throttled by a program. Every 20 minutes, a throughput status is sent on *stderr*, and I simply redirect this to a file:

```
command | cstream -t -512k -T 1200 -B 64m 2>>/home/user/totals.log | command
```

I could also send a SIGUSR1 signal to [*cstream*](http://www.cons.org/cracauer/cstream.html) (`kill -s 10 PID`) and it would produce exactly the same output as when I set an interval like I did, and a line is added to the file. The idea is that you can set the interval and also query a status on demand. The output is formatted like this with a single whitespace character all over and terminated with a newline:

```
...
1931255808 B 1.8 GB 3683.6 s (1:01 h) 524289 B/s 512.00 KB/s
2560401408 B 2.4 GB 4883.6 s (1:21 h) 524289 B/s 512.00 KB/s
3189547008 B 3.0 GB 6083.6 s (1:41 h) 524289 B/s 512.00 KB/s
3818692608 B 3.6 GB 7283.6 s (2:01 h) 524289 B/s 512.00 KB/s
4447838208 B 4.1 GB 8483.6 s (2:21 h) 524289 B/s 512.00 KB/s
10829824 B 10.3 MB 20.65 s 524487 B/s 512.19 KB/s
```

You can see the data progress but you couldn't just sum(or average) each column. There are just 2 events in this sample(lines 1-5, 6) i.e. I used the script twice. It just so happens here that we could add the two last lines - because I restarted it and we have a snapshot of that moment but that's arbitrary. Which leads to what happens when I exit the command and restart it, as you can see happening on the last line - the counter is of course reset.

The objective is to have a cumulative total of the status output for all the instances of the script I launch over time. I usually never launch more than one instance of it at a time. So I'm thinking of adding to my script("sane" for one instance of the script only):

- First delete all but the last line of my log
- Last, when the script exits, make it write its status to the log

  - Sum/avg each column of the first and last line
  - Delete all intermediary lines

I'm afraid I can't connect the dots. What is the simplest and best way to design and implement what I want? Does the complexity overwhelm the benefit and should I just focus on manipulating the log data with a simple command as it fills up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, based on what you show, I did manage to split it up pretty reliably, but there's a serious problem with this data: it's *not normal*. You've got *human-friendly* values here - that's no good. For instance the `MB` and `GB` differences between the first and last lines - handling that is a *lot* of extra work you shouldn't have to do - why not just byte counts? And what's up with the `([h]:[mm])` thing - why is it in the first line and not the last line and why not Unix time?

Honestly, this isn't the kind of data you should be logging at all - it isn't very useful. Sure, it's easier for you to read, but are you going to read 10,000 lines of it? I think you'd rather not and that's why you've asked this question. You need to alter that output - get no letters at all, only byte counts and seconds since the epoch. Do that, and this will be a *lot* easier on you.

Now, that said, here's what I *did* do:

```
set -- $(
sed '$bl;1H;d;:l;x;G
     s/([1-9][^)]*) //;h
     s/\n/First:&       /
     s/[^:]\(\n\)/&Last:\1      /
     w /dev/fd/2
     g' <<\DATA
1931255808 B 1.8 GB 3683.6 s (1:01 h) 524289 B/s 512.00 KB/s
2560401408 B 2.4 GB 4883.6 s (1:21 h) 524289 B/s 512.00 KB/s
3189547008 B 3.0 GB 6083.6 s (1:41 h) 524289 B/s 512.00 KB/s
3818692608 B 3.6 GB 7283.6 s (2:01 h) 524289 B/s 512.00 KB/s
4447838208 B 4.1 GB 8483.6 s (2:21 h) 524289 B/s 512.00 KB/s
10829824 B 10.3 MB 20.65 s 524487 B/s 512.19 KB/s
DATA
)
```

That first `sed` line is all it takes to get just your first and last lines and put them in the same pattern space for `sed` editing, each of them preceded by a `\n`ewline character. This statement does all of that:

```
$bl;1H;d;:l;x;G
```

The next line clears that funky time thing out the data - which is part of the problem - then stores an extra copy of the results in `h`old space:

```
s/([1-9][^)]*) //;h
```

The next three lines insert the words *First:* and *Last:* then `\n`ewline and `<tab>` characters before their respective lines and write the results to `stderr`:

```
 s/\n/First:&       /
 s/[^:]\(\n\)/&Last:\1      /
 w /dev/fd/2
```

The last `sed` line just `g`ets that second copy out of `h`old space and overwrites the current pattern space with it, which `sed` then follows up with its default action of printing the final pattern space followed by a `\n`ewline. The results, at this point, are, admittedly, not that impressive. Running the above bit of script will only output the following:

```
First:
        1931255808 B 1.8 GB 3683.6 s 524289 B/s 512.00 KB/s
Last:
        10829824 B 10.3 MB 20.65 s 524487 B/s 512.19 KB/s
```

But I intentionally `set` the results into the shell array *and* kept both lines accessible in `sed`'s pattern space for a reason. For instance, following that last `g` line in `sed` - if you wanted to - you could work with a pattern space that looks like this:

```
\n1931255808 B 1.8 GB 3683.6 s 524289 B/s 512.00 KB/s\n10829824 B 10.3 MB 20.65 s 524487 B/s 512.19 KB/s$
```

Or, if you left it as is and only appended the following to what's already there...

```
printf '%s LINE, FIELDs 1 and 2: %s and %s' \
    FIRST "$1" "$2" LAST "${11}" "${12}"
```

Your output should look like:

```
FIRST LINE, FIELDs 1 and 2: 1931255808 and B
LAST LINE, FIELDs 1 and 2: 10829824 and B
```

That's in addition to the `stderr` output it already provides.

Comment: Thank you! This is really insightful. It is very good advice to really analyze what that output is made of. I have to rethink this maybe. For instance removing my timer and always querying with `kill`. I could put this in a little script or alias, call this and it would send the kill and sanitize the log and update it. It's that sort of thinking that I miss as I'm very much a beginner. Then later on as I will try to build totals I will carefully analyze your `sed` processing but your general explanation is quite clear and helpful! +1

Comment: @illuminÉ - Absolutely - if you can get me a little different input, I can show you how to easily get all of your averages, totals, whatever with some very simple 3 or 4 character functions and either `dc` or `bc`.

Comment: @illuminÉ - oh, but the `kill` thing is an *excellent* idea, by the way. Try to mimic what `dd` does with `SIGUSR1` in a `trap` in your function - or even filter your output *through* `dd` for exact byte counts and `kill SIGUSR1` it from `cron` in addition to some `date` output.

Comment: Thank you! Give it a bit of time. Your answer stands. The output frequency etc. will depend on how I refactor how I trigger the writes. Maybe 1-when the script launches, 2- when the script exits, 3- when the kill alias/script is manually triggered. You've put me on the right track! fyi this is the heirloom script - just cstream is in between the random generator and `tr`.